# How can I load a SharePoint list into a tibble in R?

Tags: r, json, dataframe, dplyr, nested-lists

I want to load a SharePoint list into a tibble in R.

The problem with my attempt is, every value of the data is wrapped in a list. How can I unwrap each value or alter the data conversion to contain strings directly, not lists of lists?

```
# A tibble: 10 x 6
   `__metadata` A          B             C                D             E
   <list>       <list>     <list>        <list>           <list>        <list>    
 1 <list [4]>   <list [1]> <chr [1]>     <list [2]>       <chr [1]>     <chr [1]> 
 2 <list [4]>   <list [1]> <chr [1]>     <list [2]>       <chr [1]>     <chr [1]> 
 3 <list [4]>   <list [1]> <chr [1]>     <list [2]>       <chr [1]>     <chr [1]> 
 4 <list [4]>   <list [1]> <chr [1]>     <list [2]>       <chr [1]>     <chr [1]> 
 5 <list [4]>   <list [1]> <chr [1]>     <list [2]>       <chr [1]>     <chr [1]> 
 6 <list [4]>   <list [1]> <chr [1]>     <list [2]>       <chr [1]>     <chr [1]> 
 7 <list [4]>   <list [1]> <chr [1]>     <list [2]>       <chr [1]>     <chr [1]>
 ...
```

I tried without success:

```
my_data %>% mutate_all(~ map(.x, unlist))
my_data %>% unlist(recursive = FALSE)
```

... and many other combinations of `map()`, `mutate_all()`, `unnest()` and `unlist()`.

I think the problem lies in the way I process the data. The original JSON is in the following format:

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
        {
            "__metadata": {
            "id": "<GUID>",
            "uri": "<redacted>",
            "etag": "\"42\"",
            "type": "SP.Data.DownloadcenterItem"
            },
            "A": {
            "results": [
                {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "<GUID>",
                    "type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem"
                },
                "Title": "<redacted>"
                }
            ]
            },
            "C": {
            "__metadata": {
                "id": "<GUID>",
                "type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem"
            },
            "EMail": "<redacted>"
            },
            "B": "<redacted>",
            "D": "<redacted>",
            "E": "<redacted>"
        },
        ...
        ],
        "__next": "<redacted>"
    }
}
```

The following code is used to load the JSON and transform it into a tibble:

```
current_page <- httr::GET('<URL>') %>% httr::content()
my_data <- current_page$d$results %>%
  map(enframe) %>%
  map(~ spread(.x, name, value))
```

---

Output of `dput(current_page$d$results)`:

```
list(list(`__metadata` = list(id = "<redacted>", 
    uri = "<redacted>", 
    etag = "<redacted>", type = "<redacted>"), dmsAuthor = list(
    results = list(list(`__metadata` = list(id = "<redacted>", 
        type = "<redacted>"), Title = "<redacted>"))), 
    dmsDocumentOwner = list(`__metadata` = list(id = "<redacted>", 
        type = "<redacted>"), EMail = "<redacted>"), 
    dmsDocumentID = "<redacted>", dmsDocVersion = "<redacted>", dmsSPTitle = "<redacted>"), 
    list(`__metadata` = list(id = "<redacted>", 
        uri = "<redacted>", 
        etag = "<redacted>", type = "<redacted>"), 
        dmsAuthor = list(results = list(list(`__metadata` = list(
            id = "<redacted>", type = "<redacted>"), 
            Title = "<redacted>"))), dmsDocumentOwner = list(
            `__metadata` = list(id = "<redacted>", 
                type = "<redacted>"), EMail = "<redacted>"), 
        dmsDocumentID = "<redacted>", dmsDocVersion = "<redacted>", dmsSPTitle = "<redacted>"), 
    list(`__metadata` = list(id = "<redacted>", 
        uri = "<redacted>", 
        etag = "<redacted>", type = "<redacted>"), 
        dmsAuthor = list(results = list(list(`__metadata` = list(
            id = "<redacted>", type = "<redacted>"), 
            Title = "<redacted>"))), dmsDocumentOwner = list(
            `__metadata` = list(id = "<redacted>", 
                type = "<redacted>"), EMail = "<redacted>"), 
        dmsDocumentID = "<redacted>", dmsDocVersion = "<redacted>", dmsSPTitle = "<redacted>"), 
    list(`__metadata` = list(id = "<redacted>", 
        uri = "<redacted>", 
        etag = "<redacted>", type = "<redacted>"), 
        dmsAuthor = list(results = list(list(`__metadata` = list(
            id = "<redacted>", type = "<redacted>"), 
            Title = "<redacted>"))), dmsDocumentOwner = list(
            `__metadata` = list(id = "<redacted>", 
                type = "<redacted>"), EMail = "<redacted>"), 
        dmsDocumentID = "<redacted>", dmsDocVersion = "<redacted>", dmsSPTitle = "<redacted>"), 
    list(`__metadata` = list(id = "<redacted>", 
        uri = "<redacted>", 
        etag = "<redacted>", type = "<redacted>"), 
        dmsAuthor = list(results = list(list(`__metadata` = list(
            id = "<redacted>", type = "<redacted>"), 
            Title = "<redacted>"))), dmsDocumentOwner = list(
            `__metadata` = list(id = "<redacted>", 
                type = "<redacted>"), EMail = "<redacted>"), 
        dmsDocumentID = "<redacted>", dmsDocVersion = "<redacted>", dmsSPTitle = "<redacted>"), 
    list(`__metadata` = list(id = "<redacted>", 
        uri = "<redacted>", 
        etag = "<redacted>", type = "<redacted>"), 
        dmsAuthor = list(results = list(list(`__metadata` = list(
            id = "<redacted>", type = "<redacted>"), 
            Title = "<redacted>"))), dmsDocumentOwner = list(
            `__metadata` = list(id = "<redacted>", 
                type = "<redacted>"), EMail = "<redacted>"), 
        dmsDocumentID = "<redacted>", dmsDocVersion = "<redacted>", dmsSPTitle = "<redacted>"), 
    list(`__metadata` = list(id = "<redacted>", 
        uri = "<redacted>", 
        etag = "<redacted>", type = "<redacted>"), 
        dmsAuthor = list(results = list(list(`__metadata` = list(
            id = "<redacted>", type = "<redacted>"), 
            Title = "<redacted>"))), dmsDocumentOwner = list(
            `__metadata` = list(id = "<redacted>", 
                type = "<redacted>"), EMail = "<redacted>"), 
        dmsDocumentID = "<redacted>", dmsDocVersion = "<redacted>", dmsSPTitle = "<redacted>"), 
    list(`__metadata` = list(id = "<redacted>", 
        uri = "<redacted>", 
        etag = "<redacted>", type = "<redacted>"), 
        dmsAuthor = list(results = list(list(`__metadata` = list(
            id = "<redacted>", type = "<redacted>"), 
            Title = "<redacted>"))), dmsDocumentOwner = list(
            `__metadata` = list(id = "<redacted>", 
                type = "<redacted>"), EMail = "<redacted>"), 
        dmsDocumentID = "<redacted>", dmsDocVersion = "<redacted>", dmsSPTitle = "<redacted>"), 
    list(`__metadata` = list(id = "<redacted>", 
        uri = "<redacted>", 
        etag = "<redacted>", type = "<redacted>"), 
        dmsAuthor = list(results = list(list(`__metadata` = list(
            id = "<redacted>", type = "<redacted>"), 
            Title = "<redacted>"))), dmsDocumentOwner = list(
            `__metadata` = list(id = "<redacted>", 
                type = "<redacted>"), EMail = "<redacted>"), 
        dmsDocumentID = "<redacted>", dmsDocVersion = "<redacted>", dmsSPTitle = "<redacted>"), 
    list(`__metadata` = list(id = "<redacted>", 
        uri = "<redacted>", 
        etag = "<redacted>", type = "<redacted>"), 
        dmsAuthor = list(results = list(list(`__metadata` = list(
            id = "<redacted>", type = "<redacted>"), 
            Title = "<redacted>"))), dmsDocumentOwner = list(
            `__metadata` = list(id = "<redacted>", 
                type = "<redacted>"), EMail = "<redacted>"), 
        dmsDocumentID = "<redacted>", dmsDocVersion = "<redacted>", dmsSPTitle = "<redacted>"))
```

Comment: Cool. I think using `map_dfr(~ enframe(.x))` is not a good idea here. You need to take a step back and look into your JSON data. Figure out what you need and then extract those. Now you have a hell of nested-nested-...-nested lists. My suggestion is taking a bit of distance from the problem and thinking about it in a more general way with an open mind. Share `dput(my_data$d$results)` if you want us to help you with that. (@akrun asked for that).

Comment: OK. Let's look at the results of `enframe(unlist(current_page$d$results))`. Lots of metadata, ids, types, etc. Now you need to figure out what rows (fields of data) you want to preserve. Then, you can move to next step which is reshaping!

Comment: I want to throw away all metadata and keep the rest. `$d$results %>% map_dfr(enframe) %>% filter(name != '__metadata')` seems to throw away metadata but `unnest(value)` produces the same error as before

Comment: ```enframe(unlist(current_page$d$results)) %>% 
  filter(!grepl("metadata", name, ignore.case = T)) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(rid = 1:n()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(-rid, names_from = "name", values_from = "value") %>% 
  unnest``` This worked for me on the output of `dput` you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for your data. You don't need to use `purrr` package here.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
```

```
enframe(unlist(current_page$d$results)) %>% 
  filter(!grepl("metadata", name, ignore.case = T)) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(rid = 1:n()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(-rid, names_from = "name", values_from = "value") %>% 
  unnest

#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    dmsAuthor.resul~ dmsDocumentOwne~ dmsDocumentID dmsDocVersion dmsSPTitle
#>    <chr>            <chr>            <chr>         <chr>         <chr>     
#>  1 <redacted>       <redacted>       <redacted>    <redacted>    <redacted>
#>  2 <redacted>       <redacted>       <redacted>    <redacted>    <redacted>
#>  3 <redacted>       <redacted>       <redacted>    <redacted>    <redacted>
#>  4 <redacted>       <redacted>       <redacted>    <redacted>    <redacted>
#>  5 <redacted>       <redacted>       <redacted>    <redacted>    <redacted>
#>  6 <redacted>       <redacted>       <redacted>    <redacted>    <redacted>
#>  7 <redacted>       <redacted>       <redacted>    <redacted>    <redacted>
#>  8 <redacted>       <redacted>       <redacted>    <redacted>    <redacted>
#>  9 <redacted>       <redacted>       <redacted>    <redacted>    <redacted>
#> 10 <redacted>       <redacted>       <redacted>    <redacted>    <redacted>
```

*Warnings:*

```
#> Warning: Values in `value` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
##> * Use `values_fn = list(value = list)` to suppress this warning.
##> * Use `values_fn = list(value = length)` to identify where the duplicates arise
##> * Use `values_fn = list(value = summary_fun)` to summarise duplicates
##> Warning: `cols` is now required.
##> Please use `cols = c(dmsAuthor.results.Title, dmsDocumentOwner.EMail, dmsDocumentID, 
##>     dmsDocVersion, dmsSPTitle)`
```